# Parallel computing with parfor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to use a parallel loop in Matlab. A simplified code is as follows:

```
M = 10;
N = 10;
K = 10;
A = zeros(M,N,K);
parfor m = 1:M
    for n = 1:N
        A(m,n,1) = m;
        for k = 2:K
            A(m,n,k) = A(m,n,k-1)+randn(1);
        end
    end
end
```

It can not run successfully and Matlab tells me "Valid indices for 'A' are restricted in PARFOR loops". Hope someone know how to fix this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably make the parfor loop be the last index of the array. Try creating the array as `A = zeros(K,N,M)`.

Comment: This kind of error can be baffling indeed. Check out [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html) for a detailed explanation.